Question on caption/float spacing
I have asked two previous questions on vertical spacing (First Question: Question on overlapping parbox; Second Question: Question on overlapping tabular), and I have a final related question. As it turns out, my issue in the Second Question was really the same as the First, so apologies in advance if again this is repetitive and I'm just missing something (almost certainly the case).
I'm trying to get a float with a caption to have vertical space before and after such that all lines collapse perfectly. I have my attempt below, where I tried modifying \@caption and figure. Ultimately, I was only able to get the bottom line to overlap, with a discrepancy still with the above line.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt} % set these registers at 0pt to start
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begingroup\centering
\textcolor{red}{Figure 1: Example}
\par\endgroup

\vskip -\baselineskip

\begin{figure}[ht] % the float should be the height of one line?
\caption{Example}
\strut Control Example (red is above, blue is below)
\end{figure}

\vskip -2\baselineskip

\begingroup\centering
\textcolor{blue}{Figure 1: Example}
\par\endgroup

\makeatletter

\long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3{% looking at the definition of caption
  \par
  \addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
    {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
  \begingroup
    \@parboxrestore
    \if@minipage
      \@setminipage
    \fi
    \normalsize
    \@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces
    \strut #3\strut % added struts
    }\par
  \endgroup}

\vskip\baselineskip

\begingroup\centering
\textcolor{red}{Figure 2: Example}
\par\endgroup

\vskip -\baselineskip

\begin{figure}[ht]
\caption{Example}
\strut Now the above and below align properly.
\end{figure}

\vskip -2\baselineskip

\begingroup\centering
\textcolor{blue}{Figure 2: Example}
\par\endgroup

\newdimen\keepdepthdim % redefine the figure environment, using the solution from the First Question
\renewenvironment{figure}{\@float{figure}}{%
  \par\global\keepdepthdim=\prevdepth
  \end@float
  \par\prevdepth=\keepdepthdim
  }
\makeatother

\vskip\baselineskip

\begingroup\centering
\textcolor{red}{Figure 3: Example}
\par\endgroup

\vskip -\baselineskip

\begin{figure}[ht]
\caption{Example}
\strut Now the bottom line aligns with the caption?
\end{figure}

\vskip -2\baselineskip

\begingroup\centering
\textcolor{blue}{Figure 3: Example}
\par\endgroup

\end{document}



The baseline for \caption is at the top of the text.  Adding a \strut to the caption makes a visible difference.

You need to add a strut to the \caption and the overlaps, since you are aligning tops and bottoms instead of baselines.  Note that \ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox=\baselineskip.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt} % set these registers at 0pt to start
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begingroup\centering
\textcolor{red}{Figure 1: Example\strut}
\par\endgroup

\vskip -\baselineskip
\begin{figure}[ht] % the float should be the height of one line?
\caption{Example\strut}
%\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\caption{Example\strut}}\llap{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}
\strut Control Example (red is above, blue is below)
\end{figure}

\vskip -2\baselineskip
\begingroup\centering
\textcolor{blue}{Figure 1: Example\strut}
\par\endgroup

\end{document}


Is there a way to automate this so that I don't have to manually add \struts to the preceeding and succeeding lines? My thought is to simply add \strut to the start and end of a redefined figure environment but I'm not sure if that would be right...

Try \redefine{\figurename}{Figure\strut} although you proabably should have one at the end in case there is more than one line.
